# Очень долго загружаются тайлы OSM

Tags: render, openstreetmap, tilemap

Проблема:
тайлы загружаются очень долго (день загружаются, вообще не загружаются)

Вопрос:
Что сделать, чтобы тайлы загружались быстро? Как решить эту проблему?

Описание:
При попытке ускорить загрузку тайлов (которая изначально была долгая) сделал "рекластеринг" как описано по этой ссылке https://www.paulnorman.ca/blog/2016/06/improving-speed-with-reclustering/.
После этого тайлы стали ещё хуже загружаться. Главное, проверял сперва на испытательной базе, и всё хорошо прошло. А сделал это на рабочей базе и вот так вот вышло :/
Интересно, что "нулевое изображение" http://my_localhost/osm/0/0/0.png загружается быстро, а также ооооочень долго, но всё же, загружаются тайлы некоторые из 6-8 приближения. Остальные тайлы не загружаются.

Renderd показывает ошибку: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 34 closed, now 29 left.

Искал решение в сети, но не нашёл, потому и задаю здесь этот вопрос.

Вот скриншоты:

[image: renderd.conf]
[image: tileserver configuration 1]
[image: tileserver configuration 2]
[image: Rendering start 0]
[image: Rendering start 1]
[image: Rendering start 2]
[image: Connection closed error]

Помогите, пожалуйста. Хорошего вам дня.